# Elastic Search, Java API: Validation Failed: 1: script or doc is missing;

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am attempting to perform an Upsert on my ES system.  When I run this code below:

```
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(m);
        String id = m.getId();
        IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("mediaitems", "mediaitem", m.getId())
                .source(json);

        UpdateRequest updateRequest =
                new UpdateRequest("mediaitems", "mediaitem", m.getId()).upsert(indexRequest);
        client.update(updateRequest).get(); //Throws error here
```

it throws and error of

```
"java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestValidationException: Validation 
Failed: 1: script or doc is missing;"
```

When I comment out the UpdateRequest code, and go with a plain insert, it behaves correctly.

What is going on here?  I'm doing this because I want to avoid having to read all the documents that **might** exist on ES and then undergo an Insert-or-Update cycle.

Any help on what the problem might be is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't used Java APIs with ES but according to the error it could be that you're not setting up: `updateRequest.doc()`

Comment: Looks like Index or Type may be wrong

Comment: What is the real use case you want to implement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the correct version i.e doesn't throw errors, of the code:

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(m);
    String id = m.getId();
    IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("mediaitems", "mediaitem", m.getId())
            .source(json);

    UpdateRequest updateRequest =
            new UpdateRequest("mediaitems", "mediaitem", m.getId()).upsert(indexRequest);

    //Fix is the line below
    updateRequest.doc(indexRequest); 



    client.update(updateRequest).get();
```

Once I added the "updateRequest.doc" line from @alfasin suggestion it worked like a charm.

Comment: could be useful.. I just avoided indexRequest.

Answer (score 2):

could be useful. I faced this issue and fixed for self.  Landed here,  thought of sharing.

Similar to above,  except IndexRequest and docAsUpsert (updates doc if exists, otherwise creates one). Also creates Index for the firstime if it isn't there.

```
byte[] bytes = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(datum);
UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(topicName, "_doc", datum.getAccount_name()).doc(bytes, XContentType.JSON);
bulkProcessor.add(updateRequest);

//or

bulkProcessor.add(updateRequest.docAsUpsert(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work without throwing exception.

```
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(m);
  String id = m.getId();
  UpdateRequest updateRequest =
    new UpdateRequest("mediaitems", "mediaitem", m.getId())
    .doc(m).docAsUpsert(true);                                //assign doc
  client.update(updateRequest).get();
```